# how to combine rows and columns in html dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm currently generating tables dynamically using javascript within html. 
The following generates 3 rows and 4 columns , what can I modify to combain all column in row 3 , and rows 1 and 2 in column 2

```
    var table = '';
    var rows = 3;
    var cols = 2;
    for (var r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
      table += '<tr>';
      for (var c = 1; c <= cols; c++) {
        table += '<td id=rc' + r + c + '>' + '</td>';
      }
      table += '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: How would you do that in `HTML` ?

Comment: There is [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) attribute of `td`.

Comment: Look into rowspan and colspan attributes

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use css property "colspan" in your  like this 
`<tr colspan="4">`

hope this helps you.